# How to extract certain lines from command history in linux

Tags: linux, process, grep, command

I am trying to count the all processes opened by all commands which contain the word `valyria`. I thought about this solution:

writing a one-liner, such as `number=$(history | grep "valyria" | wc -l) && echo $number`, but this does not seem to print anything(the variable has been previously declared).

My other question is this: if I enter a command which contains the word `valyrian`, will that command open only 1 proceess or more? If the later is true, I guess that my one-liner becomes useless, since it counts 1 match=1 process. How could I achieve the desired result?

Thanks, Polb

Comment: Your shell will likely have a `history` built-in that only outputs the last few commands that were typed. You are only searching in that output. Note also that typing a command that contains a given word does not necessarily execute a process by that name. The word might have been a parameter to another command, the invocation might have resulted in a `command not found` etc

Comment: The number of processes that end up being spawned is **entirely** up to the program being run. You cannot control or count on a number for that. `history` only shows you the commands entered during interactive sessions.

Comment: Should I use a global variable such as $HISTFILE? I tryed with this too, but my command did not even finish.

Comment: If you could give some insight *why* you want to count processes, maybe this would help understand *how* best to do it.

Comment: For example I edited a file called `valyrian` several times. I used multiple commands, such as `cat valyrian`, `vim valyrian` or `stat valyrian`. All these commands have been saved in my history and everytime I launched one of these commands, a new process was started. I wanted to count all the processes so I might know how many times I did something on that file.

Comment: `history` just contains command lines, it doesn't know anything about what the programs do as a result of executing the lines.

Comment: For instance, `echo valyrian` doesn't run any processes, because `echo` is a shell built-in, but it will be counted.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you need to know the number of processes. For instance, if `vim` spawns background processes to do part of its work, why do you need to count them, instead of just counting the one `vim` command?

Comment: Actually my one-liner does not count anything yielded by the `history` command, I would be glad if it would at least count something,

Comment: You are right, I just did not express what I want clearly enough. I want to know the number of processes started by all the commands which contain the word `valyrian`

Comment: Can you describe the output of the chain of commands you use step-by-step? I feel like they should be doing exactly what you wish for (if only restricted to the last few commands, as stated earlier)